# How to display something if variable is not set inside a each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(json.data,function(i,fb){

//some code here...

if (msg.length > 150) {
                msg = msg.substr(0,200)+"...";
            }

//more code here...
});
```

I have an issue here. If msg is not defined I got an error and I got nothing displayed on the browser.

Possible Solution: create a default message for the cases where msg is not defined.

**Try:**

```
if (msg = 'undefined') {
 msg = 'some default message';
} else if (msg.length > 150) {
msg = msg.substr(0,200)+"...";
}
```

**Issue:**
The above try didn't work because I get for each item, the same default message, instead of having the default message only for those cases were msg is no "set".

**Request:**
Can I have your help in order to write the proper code so that, on each item, if msg is not defined show a default one, if otherwise, it's site, display it ?

If you lack some information in order to proper help me, please, let me know. I'm really on a bad position right now. :s

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: is msg the JSON data you received from your webservice?    Another thing I noticed is your statement should be with the == if(msg == 'undefined').  maybe post your entire AJAX call to get more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write `==` rather than `=` in your if-statement. Also, if you're trying to test if it's undefined, you should use `typeof`, like this:

```
if (typeof msg == 'undefined')
```

This idea of comparing it using `typeof` is actually safer than comparing it to the object called `undefined`. The reason is that the object can be redefined, but the result of `typeof`never changes. I dont know why anyone would be crazy enough to do it, but it is possible to write:

```
undefined = "hi there";
if (msg == undefined) // oh noes!
  ...
if (typeof msg == "undefined") // still works!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (msg = 'undefined') {
```

-->

```
if (msg == undefined) {
```

Two things

1. We use `==` to compare objects and `=` to assign variables. Even in javascript.
2. `'undefined'` is a string with text 'undefined'. `undefined` (without quotes) is a global object in javascript. Or maybe not global object, but whatever it is you can use it to check whether variable exists.

Comment: Thank you! :) (I will run now with shame). :)

Comment: This solution works for any sane situation, but it's not the recommended way to test for undefined..

Comment: undefined is not the same as null, you can pass null to a function but you cannot pass undefined to a function. Use `typeof msg == "undefined"` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
if (msg == undefined) ...
```

The trick is to use == (comparison) versus = (actually sets the variable).